# Rust integration test can't `use` library

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, nightly-build

Working to include integration tests to my project but I'm unable to import the library. I thought the new rules would allow me to just write a `use` statement but it isn't going very well :)

The code below shows the related components. Isn't this supposed to be valid?

`Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "myswankynewpackage"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Me Myself <me.myself@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
```

`tests/tests.rs`

```rust
use myswankynewpackage;
// Also tried extern crate
// extern crate myswankynewpackage;

#[cfg(test)]
mod integration {
    use super::*;

    mod module{

        #[test]
        fn module_test() {
        }
    }
}
```

I get an error saying it can't find the crate

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `myswankynewpackage`
 --> tests/tests.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use myswankynewpackage;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `myswankynewpackage` external crate
```

Comment: As a sidenote: You typically don't use `#[cfg(test)]` in the tests subfolder, because they will only be called if `cargo test` or similar is used. You can omit that :)

Comment: Have you tried it with `extern crate myswankynewpackage`?

Comment: Right I forgot about that. This is the result after a few attempts and I forgot to take it out.

Comment: Yeah, I get a `can't find crate` error

Comment: Works for me: `cargo new --lib myswankynewpackage`, add the `tests/tests.rs` file from your question, then `cargo test` → I get an unused import warning for `myswankynewpackage`, but the tests compile and run

Comment: I'm using a `Cargo.toml` from the vscode-docker dev environment. Can you post your `Cargo.toml`?

Comment: It's the straight `Cargo.toml` generated by `cargo new --lib`: [here](https://framabin.org/p/?d5bcf1b94e0240e3#d0gwoM9G8aR1fzn9EDImjngby9M1H4wHi5mU2XbaSrA=)

Comment: Using `cargo` and `rustc` version 1.37.0

Comment: I'm using `rustc 1.40.0-nightly (e413dc36a 2019-10-14)`. My `Cargo.toml` matches with it except I added a `features` section and I'm using a couple of libraries

Comment: Do you have `#[no_std]` or something in your original code somewhere? If this is a `no_std` project, you can't use rust's built-in test framework. If true, see my other answer about testing `no_std` projects [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441073/cargo-test-cannot-reference-anything-public-inside-the-targeting-crate-in-integr/58461804#58461804).

Comment: If it doesn't work in Visual Studio Code, it's VS's fault. I think it calls `rustc` directly on files, instead of `cargo`, so packages just don't work in VS Code.

Answer (score 3):

So, I noticed that [OP says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58445559/rust-integration-test-cant-use-library#comment103230912_58445559) the actual `Cargo.toml` matches the given one "except [OP is] ... using a couple of libraries."

I think what's causing problems is the libraries - if you have libraries (with a different name), you need to use the name of the library in the `use` statement. ie:

`Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "myswankynewpackage"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Me Myself <me.myself@gmail.com>"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
tests/tests.rs

[lib]
name = "myswankynewlib"
path = "src/lib.rs"
```

`tests/tests.rs`

```
// WRONG!
// use myswankynewpackage;

// RIGHT!
use myswankynewlib;

...
```

I had a similar error message, and originally found this post when searching before I realized the issue.  So even if this WASN'T the original poster's problem, perhaps this answer will help others...